# String splitting in Python

Tags: python, string

I have hex strings split by the occurance of 'ff'. Unfortunately, f can also occur within a string, and, most importantly, at the end of a string (it cannot occur at the beginning). I need to split a string such that:

```
90500303040fff90500303040fff
```

is split into:

```
90500303040f
90500303040f
```

Whats a string-based way of going about this? (currently I'm doing it on byte level, but I'd like to learn a clean string way)

Comment: Are all the hex values of equal length?

Comment: If not, you could do e.g. `re.split('ff(!?f)', ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> [e for e in re.split(r'(.*?f)?ff', '90500303040fff90500303040fff') if e]
['90500303040f', '90500303040f']
```

Or,

```
>>> re.sub(r'(f?)ff', r'\1\n', '90500303040ff90500303040fff').splitlines()
['90500303040', '90500303040f']
```

Or, non regex:

```
>>> '90500303040fff90500303040fff'.replace('fff', 'f\n').replace('ff','\n').splitlines()
['90500303040f', '90500303040f']
```